# Try these shoes or those ones?

Tags: grammar, determiners

A student of mine is taking part in an English competition and one of the multiple-choice questions she got read:
Try these shoes or those ......

a. ones
b. one
c. shoe
d. shoes

Which answer would you say is correct? Any replies appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "These shoes or those" would be sufficient, but of the alternatives I'd say (d). "Those ones" is possible but, I'd say, not standard English.

Comment: Is it permitted to help your student on the competition?

Comment: Kate: Thanks. Would you say “those shoes” would also be permissible?
GEdgar: The competition has already taken place and the test is now available on the organizer’s website, which is where I downloaded it from.

Comment: When I said 'of the alternatives I'd say (d)', I meant that, if you have to choose one of the four options, _shoes_ is the correct one.